# Next Page Selenium with Scrapy not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been struggling with the Next page button; the scraper manages to click the next page and goes to it, however, it keeps going to the first page and eventually breaks. I only want to scrape all the next pages (in this case there is only one, but might be more of them in the future).
Any ideas on what might be wrong here? Here is the code:

```
class DatatracSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'data_trac'

    start_urls = [
        # FOR SALE
        'https://www.milieuproperties.com/search-results.aspx?paramb=ADVANCE%20SEARCH:%20Province%20(Western%20Cape),%20%20Area%20(Cape%20Town)']

    def __init__(self):
        #path to driver
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('my_path')
    

    def parse(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        url = self.driver.current_url
        while True:
            try: 
                elem = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1"]/a[text()="Next"]')))
                elem.click()
            except TimeoutException:
                break
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.current_url != url)
            url = self.driver.current_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=False)

    def parse_page(self, response):

        offering = response.css('span#ContentPlaceHolder1_lblbreadcum::text').get()
        try:
            offering = 'rent' if 'Rental' in offering else 'buy'
        except TypeError:
            offering = 'buy'

        base_link = response.request.url.split('/')
        try:
            base_link = base_link[0] + '//' + base_link[2] + '/'
        except:
            pass

        for p in response.xpath('//div[@class="ct-itemProducts ct-u-marginBottom30 ct-hover"]'):
            link = base_link + p.css('a::attr(href)').get()

            yield scrapy.Request(
                link,
                callback=self.parse_property,
                meta={'item': {
                    'url': link,
                    'offering': offering,
                    }},
            )

        # follow to next page

    def parse_property(self, response):
        item = response.meta.get('item')
     . . .
```

Comment: What do you get in output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular web-site your code won't work as after you click Next button URL doesn't change. Try to wait until current page number is changed (instead of waiting for URL to change)

```
def parse(self,response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    current_page_number = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1>span').text
    while True:
        try: 
            elem = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1"]/a[text()="Next"]')))
            elem.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1>span').text != current_page_number)
        current_page_number = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1>span').text
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=False)
```

Comment: One question: what should the `url=url` be equal to? @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg `url` will be always the same. I don't think you need to check its equality

Comment: It gives me `the  name 'url' is not defined` error. Shall I replace it with `response.url `instead?  @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg oh, you mean `url` in Scrapy part. IMHO you don't need to use Scrapy at all. You can simply use Selenium built-in methods to do scraping

Comment: it still happens to get to TimeOut exception and the website keeps refreshing.. not sure what's happening @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg yes, as you can see on last page Next button is still looking enabled and clickable. You need to replace selector `'//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1"]/a[text()="Next"]'` with `'//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1"]/a[text()="Next" and not(@class)]'`

Comment: I still get  `DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:64593/session/1ddb3df63cb1cdc0b853c96593999421/element {"using": "xpath", "value": "//*[@id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1\"]/a[text()=\"Next\" and not(@class,\"aspNetDisabled\")]"}`
not sure what's up.. sorry for the spam, your help is much appreciated! @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg , note that in my previous comment I used `not(@class)` while you used `not(@class,\"aspNetDisabled\")`. These are not the same. Please try with my exact XPath

Comment: Oh sorry, I have also tried with your line, this was another try to fix it. I still get the same problem with your line @JaSON

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227893/discussion-between-jason-and-saraherceg).

Answer (score 0):

To repeatedly click the next button until the end page do the following.

```
driver.get('https://www.milieuproperties.com/search-results.aspx?paramb=ADVANCE%20SEARCH:%20Province%20(Western%20Cape),%20%20Area%20(Cape%20Town)')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'Next') and not(contains(@class,'aspNetDisabled'))]"))).click()
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check out this logic, where i was able to move to the next pages successfully

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver= webdriver.Chrome('') // Please provide your driver path here
driver.get('https://www.milieuproperties.com/search-results.aspx?paramb=ADVANCE%20SEARCH:%20Province%20(Western%20Cape),%20%20Area%20(Cape%20Town)')

driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1"]').click();
```